Situation Dependent displaywith Property with Formly Autocomplete
I'm using Formly Autocomplete in an Angular v18 project and I'm not sure how to add a displayWith property that will take some function coupled with my Formly Autocomplete field to uniquely display the properties present in the objects I am showing in my Formly field.
autocomplete-type.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'formly-autocomplete-type',
  template: `
    <input
      matInput
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [formlyAttributes]="field"
      [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete
      #auto="matAutocomplete"
      [autoActiveFirstOption]="true"
      [autoSelectActiveOption]="true"
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let value of filter | async" [value]="value">
        {{ value }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  `,
})
export class AutocompleteTypeComponent
  extends FieldType<FieldTypeConfig>
  implements OnInit {}

example of a field
{
      key: 'workCenterCode',
      type: 'autocomplete',
      props: {
        required: true,
        label: 'Work Center Code',
        placeholder: 'Work Center Code',
        filter: (term: string) =>
          of(
            term
              ? this.workOrderInputsService.filterObjectArray(
                  term,
                  this.workCenterCodeArray,
                  'NAME'
                )
              : this.workCenterCodeArray.slice()
          ),
      },
    },

I know that I can edit the autocomplete component in my project, but I'm not quite sure how to take the last step of providing a flexible value for displayWith.

Rather than using Material Autocomplete's displayWith property, access the displayProp property from the props of your Formly field.


template: `
    <input
      matInput
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [formlyAttributes]="field"
      [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete
      #auto="matAutocomplete"
      [autoActiveFirstOption]="true"
      [autoSelectActiveOption]="true"
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let value of filter | async" [value]="value">
        {{ value[props['displayProp']] }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  `,





{
      key: 'workCenterCode',
      type: 'autocomplete',
      props: {
        required: true,
        label: 'Work Center Code',
        placeholder: 'Work Center Code',
        displayProp: 'NAME',
        filter: (term: string) =>
          of(
            term
              ? this.workOrderInputsService.filterObjectArray(
                  term,
                  this.workCenterCodeArray,
                  'NAME'
                )
              : this.workCenterCodeArray.slice()
          ),
      },
    },



